# Stop the login process using async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I press login button to login into my app and 
I'm using `asyncTask` for this process. when I press the cancel button, it should stop the login process but what happens  is when I press the cancel button the dialog box goes but login process doesn't stop and evemtually the user is logged in :).

I used `asyncTaskObject.cancel(true)` to stop the process but nothing happens. How can I correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` document states that the method cancel():

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not
>   be cancelled for some other reason.

The solution is also provided in the documentation which says:

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this
>   method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After
>   invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

Check this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Comment: In my case, the process is ongoing.